# What is a parameterized reference in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Why the following line of code:

```
private static List list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

... generates the following warning:

> List is a raw type. References to
>   generic type List should be
>   parameterized.